# F# can't catch TimeoutException

Tags: exception, f#, timeout, try-catch

My question is really simple. Please take a look at screenshot:

[image]

How could that happen? I explicitly put call to Async.RunSyncronously into `try ... with`.

Comment: Maybe I do not get that properly, but i thought that by doing this, I do as follows: `async` starts new thread, and this thread waits for the `operation` to finish. And that's fine for me. I could use `let!` instead, but `let` does not allow to specify timeout and that's what I aim for.

Comment: Yep, it does. The problem might arise because my `operation` calls some COM object methods, and that's always a source of glitches. But I can't be sure about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`try/with` in F# async workflows do not map directly to CLR protected blocks - instead if exception is raised in user code, library code will catch it and re-route to the nearest error continuation (which can be i.e `with block`, `finally block`, custom error continuation supplied in `Async.StartWithContinuations` etc...). This has a consequence that debugger might report about unhandled exceptions in user code that can be handled and processed later.

Snippet below reports the similar error in debugger but nevertheless execution is finished successfully

```
let error (): int = raise (System.TimeoutException())

let run() = async {
    try 
        let result = error()
        return result
    with
    :? System.TimeoutException -> return -1
}

let r = Async.RunSynchronously (run())
printfn "%d" r
```

Comment: Wow, that's really interesting. Is that a side effect of Async computational expression implementation? And could you please suggest, what would be the best way for me to catch that damned exception? Do I get it right that I should wrap it into `StartWithContinuations`?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
let withTimeout (timeOut: option<int>) (operation: Async<'x>) : Async<option<'x>> =
  match timeOut with
   | None -> async {
       let! result = operation
       return Some result
     }
   | Some timeOut -> async {
       let! child = Async.StartChild (operation, timeOut)
       try
         let! result = child
         return Some result
       with :? System.TimeoutException ->
         return None
     }
```

You should not use `Async.RunSynchronously` within `async` blocks, because doing so makes for suboptimal use of native threads and can lead to [stack overflows](http://joeduffyblog.com/2008/02/27/hooking-clr-blocking-calls-with-synchronizationcontext/).  `Async.RunSynchronously` is for running `Async` computations from outside of such computations.  Within an `async` block you can use plain `let!` and `do!` or, for example, `Async.StartChild` to run `Async` computations.  This makes for more effective use of native threads and does not suffer from similar issues with potential stack overflows.

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot, this works, I will use your version. Though it's still interesting why my version would not work